# Calling constexpr in default template argument

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, clang, constexpr

In C++11 I am using a constexpr function as a default value for a template parameter - it looks like this:

```
template <int value>
struct bar
{
    static constexpr int get()
    {
        return value;
    }
};

template <typename A, int value = A::get()>
struct foo
{
};

int main()
{
    typedef foo<bar<0>> type;

    return 0;
}
```

G++ 4.5 and 4.7 compiles this, but Clang++ 3.1 does not. The error message from clang is:

```
clang_test.cpp:10:35: error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
template <typename A, int value = A::get()>
                                  ^~~~~~~~
clang_test.cpp:17:19: note: while checking a default template argument used here
        typedef foo<bar<3>> type;
                ~~~~~~~~~^~
clang_test.cpp:10:35: note: undefined function 'get' cannot be used in a constant expression
template <typename A, int value = A::get()>
                                  ^
clang_test.cpp:4:23: note: declared here
        static constexpr int get()
                             ^
1 error generated.
```

**Which one is correct?**

Comment: I have the same issue with clang 3.1. Any ideas on how to work around it? Do I have to use template meta programming instead of a constexpr, to be able to "call" it in a template instantiation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Richard Smith (zygoloid) at the LLVM IRC channel had a short talk with me about this issue which is your answer

```
<litb> hello folks
<litb> zygoloid, what should happen in this case?
<litb> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721130/calling-constexpr-in-default-template-argument
<litb> it seems to be clang's behavior is surprising
<litb> zygoloid, i cannot apply the "point of instantiation" rule to constexpr 
  function templates. if i call such a function template, the called definition's 
  POI often is *after* the specialization reference, which means at the point of 
  the call, the constexpr function template specialization is "undefined".
<zygoloid> it's a horrible mess. Clang does not do what the standard intends, but 
  as you note, the actual spec is gloriously unclear
<d0k> :(
<zygoloid> we should instantiate bar<3>::get(), because it is odr-used, but we 
  don't, because we incorrectly believe it's used in an unevaluated context
<zygoloid> conversely, the point of instantiation is too late :/
<zygoloid> PR11851
```

So it seems that sometimes, Clang instantiates called function templates or member function of class templates but their instantiation is too late for the call to see, and at other cases it doesn't even instantiate them because it thinks it will never need them (unevaluated context).

Comment: For those who want to follow the development, look at the bugzilla entry at http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=11851

Comment: This should now be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I think GCC <s>Clang</s> is correct

quoted from n3290:

> 14.3.2 Template non-type arguments [temp.arg.nontype]
>
> 1. A template-argument for a non-type, non-template template-parameter shall be one of:
>
>    - for a non-type template-parameter of integral or enumeration type, a converted > constant expression (5.19) of the type of the template-parameter; or
>
>      ...

EDIT: 5.19 3

> A literal constant expression is a prvalue core constant expression of
> literal type, but not pointer type. An integral constant expression is
> a literal constant expression of integral or unscoped enumeration
> type. [ Note: Such expressions may be used as array bounds (8.3.4,
> 5.3.4), as bit-field lengths (9.6), as enumerator initializers if the underlying type is not fixed (7.2), as null pointer constants (4.10),
> and as alignments (7.6.2). —end note ] A converted constant expression
> of type T is a literal constant expression, implicitly converted to
> type T, where the implicit conversion (if any) is permitted in a
> literal constant expression and the implicit conversion sequence
> contains only user-defined conversions, lvalue-to-rvalue conversions
> (4.1), integral promotions (4.5), and integral conversions (4.7) other
> than narrowing conversions (8.5.4).
>
> [ Note: such expressions may be used as case expressions (6.4.2), as enumerator initializers if the underlying type is fixed (7.2), and as integral or enumeration non-type template arguments (14.3). —end note ]

Comment: @cschwan: Sorry, i was wrong, havent read all of 5.19. Clang is correct, see my edit.

Comment: Ok, help me a bit: In my case the default value for `value` must be a "converted constant expression". 5.19.3 now states that `A::get()` is not a constant expression because it is none of the items listed in it, right?

Comment: `A::get()` is a `core constant expresion` (described in 5.19.2), but not a `converted constant expression`

Comment: why is it not a converted constant expression?

Comment: A literal constant expression is a prvalue core constant expression of literal non-pointer type. As you already agree that `A::get()` is a core constant expression, and as I think there's no argument that it's a prvalue of literal non-pointer type, `A::get()` is a literal constant expression. A literal constant expression without any implicit conversions is also a converted constant expression, according to the text you quoted. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Daniel Krügler also disagrees with litb, see http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53464

Comment: I think I wanted to say "... disagrees with *smerlin*", not litb.

Comment: yeah, i really have to make sure that the next time i want to proof something based on the standard that i read and quote the complete paragraphs thoroughly first.

Comment: I think it would also have happened to me :)