# Constexpr decltype

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, constexpr

I recently asked a question here ([Detecting instance method constexpr with SFINAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231982/detecting-instance-method-constexpr-with-sfinae)) where I tried to do some constexpr detection at compile time. Eventually, I figured out that one can exploit `noexcept` to do this: any constant expression is also `noexcept`. So I put together the following machinery:

```
template <class T>
constexpr int maybe_noexcept(T && t) { return 0; }
...
constexpr bool b = noexcept(maybe_noexcept(int{}));
```

This works and `b` is true as you'd expect, as zero-initializing an `int` is a constant expression. It also correctly yields zero when it should (if I change `int` to some other appropriate type).

Next, I wanted to check if something is `constexpr` move constructible. So I did this:

```
constexpr bool b = noexcept(maybe_noexcept(int(int{})));
```

And again, this works properly for `int`, or a user defined type. However, this checks that the type has both a constexpr default constructor and a constexpr move constructor. So, to work around this, I tried to change to declval:

```
constexpr bool b = noexcept(maybe_noexcept(int(declval<int>())));
```

This results in `b` being false in gcc 5.3.0 (can't use clang for any of this, because clang does not correctly make constant expressions `noexcept`). No problem, I say, must be because `declval` is (interestingly enough) not marked `constexpr`. So I write my own naive version:

```
template <class T>
constexpr T&& constexpr_declval() noexcept;
```

Yes, this is naive compared to how the standard library does it as it will choke on void and probably other things, but it's fine for now. So I try again:

```
constexpr bool b = noexcept(maybe_noexcept(int(constexpr_declval<int>())));
```

This still does not work, `b` is always false. Why is this not considered a constant expression? Is this a compiler bug, or am I not understanding fundamental about `constexpr`? It seems like there is some strange interaction between `constexpr` and unevaluated contexts.

Comment: @Cameron The second part of what you said is certainly true, but the first technically is not. Every constant expression *is* ``noexcept``, it's not that it may be. However, the return of a ``constexpr`` function is not always a constant expression.

Comment: Your function call is not a constant expression because it is undefined ([expr.const]/2.3)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`constexpr` expressions must be defined.  Yours is not defined, so in that case `int(constexpr_declval<int>())` is not `constexpr`.

Which means `maybe_noexcept(int(constexpr_declval<int>()))` is not a `constexpr`, so is not `noexcept`.

And the compiler properly returns `false`.

You also cannot invoke UB in a `constexpr`.

I cannot think of a way to make a `constexpr` reference to arbitrary data.  I was thinking a `constexpr` buffer of aligned storage reinterpreted as a reference to the data type, but that is UB in many contexts, hence not-`constexpr`.

In general, this isn't possible.  Imagine you had a class whose state determines if the method call is `constexpr`:

```
struct bob {
  int alice;
  constexpr bob(int a=0):alice(a) {}
  constexpr int get() const {
    if (alice > 0) throw std::string("nope");
    return alice;
  }
};
```

now, is `bob::get` `constexpr` or not?  It is if you have a `constexpr bob` constructed with a non-positive `alice`, and ... it isn't if not.

You cannot say "pretend this value is `constexpr` and tell me if some expression is `constexpr`".  Even if you could, it wouldn't solve the problem in general, because the *state* of a `constexpr` parameter can change if an expression is `constexpr` or not!

Even more fun, `bob().get()` *is constexpr*, while `bob(1).get()` is not.  So your first attempt (default construct the type) even gave the wrong answer: you can test, then do the action, and the action will fail.

The object is effectively a parameter to the method, and without the state of al parameters, you cannot determine if a function is `constexpr`.

The way to determine if an expression is `constexpr` is to run it in a `constexpr` context and see if it works.

Comment: So it seems like it is actually just impossible to properly test if constexpr instance methods exist for a class, because you need to get an instance to do that, and there is no way to get a constexpr instance that is both actually defined and does not assume the existence of some constructor. Is this a fair description of the situation?

Comment: @NirFriedman Well, you can pass in arguments to construct said object.  ;)  In general, `constexpr` is context dependent -- you need to know almost *everything* about the call and its parameters.  One of the parameters is the object *doing the call*: if it isn't `constexpr` the expression is (in general) not.  Saying "if pretend this argument is `constexpr` even though it isn't what happens" is not supported, as far as I know.

Comment: Haha indeed. Alright, your answer + comment were very informative, thank you.

Comment: @NirFriedman I added a clear concrete example of why what you are asking isn't really possible in the question.

Comment: Wow, thanks for that example, very insightful. That's definitely food for thought. I think I'm starting to understand better why constexpr has this weird status where it's not first class in the type system like const. I do still wish they would make it possible to make things conditionally constexpr, the way you can with noexcept(...). I can live with crappier detection (rarely makes a difference in practice), but I'm going to need to write SFINAE overloads using my detector... seems painful and unnecessary. Unless there's some reason why constexpr(compile_time_boolean) wouldn't work...