# Using SFINAE to check whether function is constexpr or not

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr, sfinae, compile-time

I want to check whether a function can be evaluated during compilation. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232758/detecting-constexpr-with-sfinae), but I don't understand the concept completely. I have a few doubts:

1. What is the role of the following line in the code?
   `template<int Value = Trait::f()>`
2. Every time when I need to check whether the function is compile-time evaluable, Do I need to make it a member function of some struct?

**PS**
I am copying the code in the link, just for convenience.

```cpp
template<typename Trait>
struct test
{
    template<int Value = Trait::f()>
    static std::true_type do_call(int){ return std::true_type(); }

    static std::false_type do_call(...){ return std::false_type(); }

    static bool call(){ return do_call(0); }
};

struct trait
{
    static int f(){ return 15; }
};

struct ctrait
{
    static constexpr int f(){ return 20; }
};

int main()
{
   std::cout << "regular: " << test<trait>::call() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "constexpr: " << test<ctrait>::call() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: In the grand scheme of things, there are far, far more useless questions that get constantly posted here, so here's an upvote, to counter-balance the downvote. Don't pay too much attention to stray downvotes, they're just collateral damage...

Comment: `template<int Value = Trait::f()>` effectively requires that `Trait::f()` can be evaluated at compile time. If it cannot be, this overload does not participate in overload resolution. If it is present, it is the best match for `do_call(0);` but if it is eliminated then `do_call(...)` becomes the best match.

Comment: Additional issue is that `constexpr` functions might only be used in constant expression for a given subset of possible parameters. so `f(0)` is not valid whereas `f(42)` is (`constexpr int f(int i) { if (i == 0)  throw std::runtime_error(".."); return i;}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is just a quick example of what you can get with [`std::void_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) to tackle your point 2 that can be generic in some way...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int f() {
    return 666;
}

constexpr int cf(int, double) {
    return 999;
}

template <auto F>
struct indirection {
};

template<typename F, class = std::void_t<> >
struct is_constexpr : std::false_type { };

template<typename F, typename... Args>
struct is_constexpr<F(Args...),
           std::void_t<indirection<F(Args{}...)>>
       > : std::true_type { };

int main()
{
   std::cout << is_constexpr<decltype(f)>::value << std::endl;
   std::cout << is_constexpr<decltype(cf)>::value << std::endl;
};
```

[Demo here](https://godbolt.org/z/bEjPa3)

Comment: value is not declared.

Comment: @Kishan Shukla I added a demo link

Comment: Notice that you check only if `cf(0, 0)` can be used in constant expression. other values might be not valid, and you require your arguments to be default constexpr constructible.