# Compile time selectable code standard question

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

For an embedded system, I've written a code that's generating a delay based on a compile-time and run-time selected variable. The compile-time version boils down to writting as much NOP instruction as required for reaching the expected CPU cycle count.

The main part is like this:

```
#define IS_CONSTEXPR(...) __builtin_constant_p(__VA_ARGS__)
#define FORCE_INLINE      __attribute__((always_inline))

template <int a> struct Nop { 
    __attribute__((always_inline)) static void nop() {
      asm __volatile__("nop");
      Nop<a-1>::nop();
    }
};
template <> struct Nop<0> {
    __attribute__((always_inline)) static void nop() {}
};

void bar(int x) { 
    // TODO: Make an asm version of this to avoid depending on compiler optimization
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) 
      Nop<1>::nop(); 
}

template <bool e, int T> struct CTorRT
{   
  FORCE_INLINE CTorRT(int) { 
    if (T == 0) return;
    if (T >= 40) bar(T - 10); // Switch to loop based delay now, since it's above the loop calling overhead 
    else Nop<T>::nop(); // Let's generate a bunch of nop!
  }
};

template <int T> struct CTorRT<false, T>
{
    FORCE_INLINE CTorRT(int v) { bar(v); }
};


#define DELAY_CYCLE(X) { CTorRT<IS_CONSTEXPR(X), IS_CONSTEXPR(X) ? X : 0> a(X); }


int main()
{
   int d = 10;
[...]
   DELAY_CYCLE(30);  // Generates 30 NOP 
   DELAY_CYCLE(d);   // Call bar(10) and loop 10 times over a single NOP loop
[...]
}
```

The code works as [expected](https://godbolt.org/z/bqfM7n) on all compilers (except for the oldest ones)

Yet, I've trouble understanding why it's not breaking on this part: `CTorRT< A, A ? X : 0>`.
`A` is a compile time constant (constexpr), yet X can be a dynamic variable, and as such, my understanding is that `A ? X : 0` is not a constexpr (even if the result is obviously a constant expression in all cases).

What part of the standard implies that the expression: "constexpr_bool ? variable_or_constexpr : constexpr" is a constexpr ?

Comment: Where is that `CTorRT< A, A ? X : 0>`?

Comment: In the macro "DELAY_CYCLE(X)". `A` contains the "constexpr-ness" of X

Comment: So what? Macros are not code. Are you familiar with how macros work?

Comment: Basically, it works this way: If X is a constexpr, it's used as a template parameter of CTorRT template. If X is not a constexpr, the template parameter is 0 and X is used in the constructor of CTorRT

Comment: Sure, but this means absolutely nothing, whatosever, in a macro definition. Now, try ***using*** this macro with a non-constant macro, and see if it works.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Of course I am. Please read the code again. The DELAY_CYCLE macro is actually generating code, I'm using the macro to avoid repeating X parameter 4 times. The example usage code is provided in the link. It's not actually required that it's called to answer the question, IMHO.

Comment: @xryl669 I see the macro, but I don't know how you use it. Please include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You can click on the link, to see an example. It's not that hard...

Comment: The `DELAY_CYCLE` macro definition, shown above, does not generate any code, whatsoever. Macros don't work this way. When you ***use*** a macro, only ***then*** you are generating code. A good C++ textbook will have a fuller explanation of how macros work. You will be surprised to learn that you can replace the definition of DELAY_CYCLE with a full implementation of The Sieve Of Erathothenes, and this will still not generate a single byte of code.

Comment: @xryl669 So you mean the people you're asking to spend their time to help you should do these effort rather than yourself?

Comment: If you clicked on "as expected", as expected, you'd have see the macro instantiated. Yet, I've edited the question so it's being instantiated here too.

Comment: Now, it's a different story. This is why stackoverflow.com's [help] requires a [mre]. The shown code relies on non-standard, compiler-specific, C++ that always produces a constant expression which can be evaluated at compile-time.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Can you elaborate as an answer ? What part of the standard says that the behavior of the compiler is implementation specific ? How to do the same thing in a standard compliant way ?

Comment: @xryl669 Thanks. Finally all necessary information on one screen. No need to be rude to people willing to help you, BTW. You simply increase the chance of getting an answer.

Comment: For example, if I could have used C++20, I could have replaced the IS_CONSTEXPR(X) via a function wrapper over `std::is_constant_evaluated()` so, this part is clear to me.

Comment: Yet, from this [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-patches/2011-10/msg01944.html), the gcc's `__builtin_choose_expr` only exists in C code, and the justification seems that it's possible to do the same in C++ in a standard way. I've something working, but I'm not sure if it's the intended way of doing it and in that case, why?

Comment: @xryl669 AFAIK this is the only standard-compliant way, don't think this is possible in c++17 and earlier.

Comment: Buried somewhere in the standard: all symbols that begin with a double-underscore are reserved for a compiler's own use as is entirely up to the compiler's use for whatever it wants. Here the compiler waves a magic wand and says: if you use it like that you always get a constant expression. Reserved symbols are mentioned in most textbooks. it would take too much time to dig through a 2000 page standard to locate the right clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What part of the standard implies that the expression: "constexpr_bool ? variable_or_constexpr : constexpr" is a constexpr ?

No part does, because `__builtin_constant_p` is not a standard function (or a regular function at all), and that ternary would *not* normally be a `constexpr`. You're using the documented behaviour of a compiler extension, not the standard language at all.

The [GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-_005f_005fbuiltin_005fconstant_005fp) specifically address this:

> You may also use `__builtin_constant_p` in initializers for static data. For instance, you can write

```c
static const int table[] = {
    __builtin_constant_p (EXPRESSION) ? (EXPRESSION) : -1,
    /* … */
};
```

> **This is an acceptable initializer even if EXPRESSION is not a constant expression** ...

That is, GCC effectively implemented `?constexpr` just for their own builtin. This doesn't imply there's *any* way to achieve the same thing *except* when using such a compiler extension.

Comment: Ok, it's clear. So the question boils down to [how to apply SFINAE on constexpr-ness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232758) in C++ for 2 different implementations (compile time & runtime)