# Must template argument functions be treated as potentially constexpr?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer, constexpr

Consider this program:

```
template <int F(), int N = F()>
void f() { }
constexpr int g() { return 1; }
int main() { f<g>(); }
```

Is this valid? Are compilers required to see at template definition time, that `F` could potentially refer to a `constexpr` function, and therefore the default argument for `N` could be valid?

gcc and clang accept this, but Intel<sup>1</sup> rejects the template function at template definition time because `F()` is not a constant expression. Intel does accept `f<g, g()>()` if the default argument is removed, so clearly it understands that `g()` is usable in a constant expression in general.

It's not clear to me what the standard says. It's clear that (C++11 [expr.const]p2)

> an invocation of a function other than a `constexpr` constructor for a literal class or a `constexpr` function

renders an expression non-constant, but it's not clear to me whether that applies here. At template definition time, it certainly does seem to apply, since `F` is not declared to be a `constexpr` function, but at the same time, errors at template definition time are supposed to be diagnosed only if there is no possible valid instantiation of the template, and there does appear to be a valid instantiation here.

I can see the arguments for both answers, so I'm getting confused. Is there a definitive answer to this question?

<sub><sup>1.</sup> Re-testing with the current release of Intel's compiler shows that it works just fine, so presumably the Intel developers considered it a bug and have since fixed it. This is a huge hint that the code is meant to be valid. It would still be nice to get a conclusive answer based on the standard, though.</sub>

Comment: Side note: that's adjusted to a pointer-to-function.

Comment: I'd guess this is ill-formed, since `F()` is not `constexpr` so wouldn't qualify as a "constant expression" as per [temp.arg.nontype].

Comment: Possibly relevent? [N4198](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4198.html)

Comment: @T.C. Sure. A reference to a function works the same way, FWIW: accepted by gcc and clang, rejected by Intel.

Comment: @Barry I think that's a slightly different issue, and I don't think the suggested re-wording would answer my question one way or the other. It's a similar sort of issue, though. :)

Comment: @Barry not convinced that is the issue, but it did come up before [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27410465/1708801)

Comment: @T.C. I don't think that's a side-node. One had to check the constant expression rules for the restrictions on pointers-to-functions.

Comment: @dyp All three compilers agree that `constexpr` pointers to functions don't add anything special: all three accept `constexpr int f() { return 0; } constexpr int (*fp)() = f; constexpr int g = fp(); int main() { return g; }`. I didn't think it worth mentioning, but if you disagree, I can include a note of that in the question.

Comment: @hvd Hm. It seems irrelevant since there's no indirection performed: The function-call expression accepts pointers directly.

Comment: Possibly, the standard is underspecified here: it seems there's no description of what's happening in a function call expression when the postfix-expression is a pointer-to-function. Certainly, `int (*fp)() = f; constexpr int x = fp();` is supposed to be forbidden, but I can't see the rule it violates (l-t-r?)

Comment: @dyp That is invalid because it involves the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of `fp`, and the rules on when lvalue-to-rvalue conversions can appear in constant expressions cover it. In my example, `fp` is "a glvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile object defined with `constexpr`", which is one of the exceptions, but not so in your example.

Comment: Does the Intel compiler complain about something like `template<class T, int y = F<T>()>`, where `F` is conditionally `constexpr`? If it accepts that pointers-to-functions can be used in constant expressions, the issue seems to be the check at template definition time, which seems to reject conditionally-constant expressions.

Comment: @dyp Heh, nice. `template <typename T> int f(); template <> constexpr int f<int>() { return 0; } template <typename T, int N = f<T>()> int g() { return N; } int main() { return g<int>(); }` produces "internal error: assertion failed at: "shared/cfe/edgcpfe/exprutil.c", line 11056". :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Introduction

```
template<int F(), int N = F()> void func ();
```

In this answer we will go through the relevant sections of the International Standard, step by step, to prove that the above snippet is well-formed.

---

#### What does the International Standard ([N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)) say?

**The Standardese**

> 14.1p9 **Template parameters** `[temp.param]`
>
> > A *default template-argument* is a *template-argument* (14.3) specified after `=` in a *template-parameter*. **[...]**

> 14.3p6 **Template arguments** `[temp.arg]`
>
> If the use of a *template-argument* gives rise to an ill-formed construct in the instantiation of a template specialization, the program is ill-formed.

> 14.3.2p1 **Template non-type arguments** `[temp.arg.nontype]`
>
> > A *template-argument* for a non-type, non-template *template-parameter* shall be one of:
> >
> > - for a non-type *template-parameter* of integral or enumeration type, a converted constant expression (5.19) of the type of the *template-parameter*; or
> > - the name of a non-type *template-parameter*; or
> > - a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of an object **[...]**; or
> > - a constant expression that evaluates to a null pointer value (4.10); or
> > - a constant expression that evaluates to a null member pointer value (4.11); or
> > - a pointer to member expressed as described in 5.3.1

> 5.19p3 **Constant expressions** `[expr.const]`
>
> > A *literal constant expression* is a prvalue core constant expression of
> >     literal type, but not pointer type. An *integral constant expression* is a
> >     literal constant expression of integral or unscoped enumeration type. A *converted constant expression* of type `T` is a literal constant expression,
> >     implicitly converted to the type `T`, **[...]**

> 8.3.6p3 **Default arguments** `[dcl.fct.default]`
>
> > A default argument shall be specified only in the *parameter-declaration-clause* of a function declaration or in a *template-parameter* (14.1); in the latter case, the *initializer-clause* shall be an *assignment-expression*.

**The Verdict**

The above sections makes us come to the following conclusions:

- A *default template-argument* is a *template-argument*, and;
- when instantiating a template, all *template-arguments* must be usable in the context where they appear, and;
- every *template-argument* for a non-type, non-template *template-parameter* that appears in a program must be a *literal constant expression*, and;
- the *default-argument* for a *template-parameter* shall be an *assignment-expression*.

---

#### The Explanation

```
template<int F(), int N = F()>
void func ();
```

```
constexpr int (*F)() = <some_initializer>;                    // (A)
constexpr int N      = <explicit_template_argument> OR <F()>  // (B)
```

The snippet above can be used as a mental helper to ease reasoning about what the *template-parameters* will be equivalent to, given a set of *template-arguments*.

To see whether *(B)* is valid or not, where an explicit *template-argument* is not given for *N*, we must evaluate *(A)* - and the evaluation of *(A)* might yield a value for *F* that is usable in the *constant-expression* required by *(B)*.

With that said; **Yes**, the template is legal C++11.

<sub>**Legal**</sub>

```
constexpr int g () { ... }
```

```
// func<&g> 
constexpr int (*F)() = &g;  // ok
constexpr int N      = F(); // ok
```

<sub>**Ill-formed**</sub>

```
          int f () { ... }
```

```
// func<&f>
constexpr int (*F)() = &f;  // ok
constexpr int N      = F(); // ill-formed, not a constant-expression
```

---

#### Bonus

The same set of rules apply to the following template;

```
template<int X, int N = 100/X>
void gunc ();
```

```
gunc<0> (); // ill-formed, `100/0` is not mathematically defined,
            //              and is therefore not a constant-expression
```

<sub>**For the language-lawyer**</sub>

And this, pointless use of a default *template-argument*, is actually legal since `F()` might be a *constant-expression*.

`F()` can however **not** be a *converted constant-expression* to give *N* a value, but this doesn't happen until (if ever) the *default argument* is actually used.

```
template<void F(), int N = F()>
void hunc ();
```

```
void f ();

hunc<&f, 10> (); // legal
hunc<&f    > (); // ill-formed
```

Comment: Your bonus gives an interesting case where GCC and clang disagree. `template <int = 1/0> void f() { } int main() { f<0>(); }` Valid or not? GCC thinks so (accepting it even with `-std=c++11 -pedantic-errors`), clang rejects it regardless of command-line options. As for the rest of your answer, thanks, you raise some interesting points. I'm not entirely convinced yet, but I'll re-read it in a bit to check if perhaps I missed something that you did already address.

Comment: @hvd I'll add another bonus shortly, `template<int = 1/0> void f;` is *ill-formed* because `1/0` is **not** a *constant-expression* (whereas `F()`, in the previous examples, **can** be a *constant-expression*).

Comment: But your answer doesn't say that template default arguments must be constant expressions, and indeed that wouldn't be a reasonable requirement, since `100/X` *isn't* a constant expression at template definition time, it only *becomes* a constant expression after a non-zero value is substituted for `X` during instantiation. In my example, that never happens, because the only template instantiation explicitly specifies an argument.

Comment: @hvd mind the use of *"converted constant-expression"*, this says that the expression itself must be a *constant-expression*; I'll make this more explicit by adding the relevant section of the standard to the answer.

Comment: I certainly agree that `f<>` or `f<1 / 0>` would be invalid. That is indeed ruled out by what you quote: a template argument must be a (converted) constant expression, and `1 / 0` doesn't qualify. But in `template <int = 1/0> void f() { }`, there is no template argument that has a non-constant value, because a template default argument isn't a template argument, except if it eventually ends up used. (N3337 incorrectly talks about the requirements of template parameters, that has been fixed to refer to template arguments in later drafts.)

Comment: Basically, if I follow the logic in your answer, and that logic does seem valid, then I agree that the code in my question is valid, but `template <int = 1/0> void f() { }` seems to be valid for the exact same reason, and you say that *that* is invalid. So, I'm probably misunderstanding the logic in your answer.

Comment: @hvd No, and now I realized that I quoted the standard incorrectly.. it should be *"a template-**argument** for a non-type, non-template template-parameter"* - I'll fix the answer, sorry for the confusion. (the reason for the misquote is that I can't copy+paste from my pdf-reader so I type it out manually).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71874/discussion-between-filip-roseen-refp-and-hvd).

Comment: Re-reading the standard and the comments here, I think there is something very simple that I missed: at template definition time, there is no "invocation of a function other than a `constexpr` constructor for a literal class or a `constexpr` function", because `F` simply isn't a function and cannot be found to refer to *any* function, `constexpr` or otherwise. You did clear up a lot of my confusion, and I think I now agree with everything you wrote. I'm not particularly happy about some of the wording in the standard, but that's beyond of the scope of my question, and not your fault anyway. :)