# Non-type reference parameter/argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, reference, non-type

Why is it that the template argument of a non-type reference cannot be another reference (g++ 4.8.1):

```
template <int& N> void test() { }

int x = 5;
int& p = x;

int main(){
    test<x>(); //compiles fine
    test<p>(); //error: could not convert template argument 'p' to 'int&'|  
}
```

I can't see where from the standard `p` is violating anything, these seemed the most relevant sections (N3337):

> [14.3.2] [.1] A template-argument for a non-type, non-template template-parameter shall be one of:
>
> — for a non-type template-parameter of integral or enumeration type, a converted constant expression (5.19) of the type of the template-parameter; or
>
> — the name of a non-type template-parameter; or
>
> — a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of an object with static storage duration and external or internal linkage or a function with external or internal linkage, including function templates
>   and function template-ids but excluding non-static class members, expressed (ignoring parentheses) as & id-expression, except that the & may be omitted if the name refers to a function or array and shall be omitted if the corresponding template-parameter is a reference; or .....
>
> [.4]
>
> [ Note: Temporaries, unnamed lvalues, and named lvalues with no linkage are not acceptable templatearguments
>   when the corresponding template-parameter has reference type.
>
> [.5]
>
> — For a non-type template-parameter of type reference to object, no conversions apply. The type referred
>   to by the reference may be more cv-qualified than the (otherwise identical) type of the templateargument.
>   The template-parameter is bound directly to the template-argument, which shall be an
>   lvalue.

`p` should be considered an lvalue shouldn't it? The only other thing I could think of was maybe a lack of linkage for references but adding `extern int& p = x` didn't fix it either.

Comment: Looks related to [template instantiation with constexpr function failure](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27410465/1708801)

Comment: Seems to be changed for the upcoming [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) standard, with [N4268, Allow constant evaluation for all non-type template arguments](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4268.html).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes, that is exactly the proposal that is mentioned in the question I linked above. It took a little while to determine which exact changes applied in this case. The previous was simpler since the proposals example covered the OPs case exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is related to the previous question [template instantiation with constexpr function failure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27410465/1708801) which I linked to a while ago in the comments, although your case is different.

It looks the example was previously not allowed but support was added in to C++1z via the proposal [Allow constant evaluation for all non-type template arguments](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4198.html) which opens with:

> the syntactic restrictions for pointers, references, and pointers to
>   members are awkward and prevent reasonable refactorings. [...] The
>   historical reason for the restriction was most likely that C++
>   previously did not have a sufficiently strong specification for
>   constant expressions of pointer, reference, or pointer-to-member type.
>   However, that is no longer the case.  [...]

The specific changes that seems relevant to your case is the rewording of the draft C++ standard section `14.3.2` Template non-type arguments [temp.arg.nontype]/p1 from:

> A template-argument for a non-type, non-template template-parameter shall be one of:
>
> [...]
>
> - a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of a complete object with static storage durationtion
>     and external or internal linkage or a function with external or internal linkage, including function
>     templates and function template-ids but excluding non-static class members, expressed (ignoring parentheses)
>     as & id-expression, where the id-expression is the name of an object or function, except that the
>     & may be omitted if the name refers to a function or array and shall be omitted if the corresponding
>     template-parameter is a reference; or
>
> [...]

to:

> A template-argument for a non-type template-parameter shall be a converted constant expression (5.20) of
>   the type of the template-parameter. For a non-type template-parameter of reference or pointer type, the
>   value of the constant expression shall not refer to (or for a pointer type, shall not be the address of):
>
> - a subobject (1.8),
> - a temporary object (12.2),
> - a string literal (2.13.5),
> - the result of a typeid expression (5.2.8), or
> - a predefined **func** variable (8.4.1).

and a change of section `5.20` Constant expressions [expr.const]/p4 has the following paragraph on converted constant expressions, which starts out:

> A converted constant expression of type T is an expression, implicitly converted to type T, where the converted
>   expression is a constant expression and the implicit conversion sequence contains only

and this in particular was added:

> [...] and where the reference binding (if any) binds directly [...]

Note, the current head version of clang compiles your code in C++1z mode, [see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/9diCkvKpPBhJ6boQ).

The updated version of the [N4268](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4268.html) was the one applied and [clang C++1z implementation status section](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) indicates this paper was support from clang 3.6. This code only works in C++1z mode for clang 3.6 and greater.

Answer (score 2):

Using the simplified wording introduced by N4268 (and now in the WD),

> A *template-argument* for a non-type template-parameter **shall be a
>   converted constant expression (5.20) of the type of the *template-parameter***. For a non-type *template-parameter* of reference […] type, the
>   value of the constant expression shall not refer to […]: […cases that don't apply…]

"converted constant expression" is defined in [expr.const]/4:

> A *converted constant expression* of type `T` is an expression,
>   implicitly converted to type `T`, where the converted expression is a
>   constant expression and the implicit conversion sequence contains
>   only […] and where the reference binding (if any) binds directly.

Clearly, the reference binds directly. Are `x` and `p` constant expressions in this context?

[expr.const]/5:

> A *constant expression* is either a glvalue core constant expression
>   whose value refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a
>   constant expression (as defined below), or […]

A permitted result of a constant expression is defined in the next paragraph as

> …an object with static storage duration that is either not a temporary object or […]

`x` and `p` do refer to an object with static storage duration, but are they core constant expressions in the given context? The answer is yes: As long as their *value* (or the value of the object `p` refers to) is not examined by the expression, which it isn't, everything's fine, even for `p`:

> A *conditional-expression* `e` is a *core constant expression* unless the evaluation of `e` […] would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> — an *id-expression* that refers to a variable or data member of
>   reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and
>   either
>
> - it is initialized with a constant expression

`x` as the initializer of `p` is a constant expression (just as it is a valid template-argument for `int&`), hence `p` as the template-argument is a constant expression as well.

Note that [Clang as of version 3.6](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/1Ev5WcKFEQokx81O) compiles your snippet fine.