# non-type template parameter : how to pass reference to base class object?

Tags: c++

It does not seem to be possible to pass a reference to 
the base class object of a derived object as a template parameter,
as I try to do here:

```
struct a
{ int _v;
  constexpr a():_v(0){}
  constexpr a(int v): _v(v){} 
};

struct c: public a
{ constexpr c():a(){}
  constexpr c(int v):a(v){} 
};

extern const c default_a;

constexpr const c default_a { 1 };

const a& c_as_a = default_a;
//    ^-- this line (16) causes no error - c can be converted to a

template < const a & The_A = default_a >
struct b
{ constexpr static const a &the_a = The_A;
};

b<> a_b;

// Template instantiation causes error:
// t.C:24:7: error: could not convert template argument 'default_a' to 'const a&'
// b<> a_b;
//   ^
```

I would have expected the 'c' object 'default_a', since it is derived from
'a', to be acceptable as a 'const a&', as it is on the line 16.

Why isn't this OK as a template parameter ?

What section of specification actually mandates this behaviour ?

Maybe my build of gcc-5.3.0 is somehow defective ?

Anyone found a good workaround / way of passing a derived object as a base class object reference template parameter ?

I cannot just substitute the reference variable 'c_as_a' for 'default_a' in
template argument list:

```
template < const a & The_A = c_as_a >
```

t.C:24:7: error: 'const a& c_as_a' is not a valid template argument for type 'const a&' because a reference variable does not have a constant address
     b<> a_b;

Nor can I substitute any constexpr function call which does something like:

```
 constexpr const a& c_as_a( const c &c ){ return *reinterpret_cast<const a*>(&c);}
 ...
 template < const a & The_A = c_as_a( default_a ) >
```

since this call is not an 'object with external linkage'.

Any suggestions how to achieve passing a reference to a base class of a derived object as a template parameter would be much appreciated - it's
got to be possible, I just can't see how ATM.

There must be a way of specifying a reference to an object's base class object as a template parameter.

Comment: in C++14 the non-type template parameter `const a &` can only bind directly to a named lvalue with linkage. So you're out of luck. In C++17 this will be allowed to bind to some more things, [see here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters)

Comment: Thanks M.M - sorry for initial 'The_A = c' typo - corrected now.

Comment: OK, thanks for confirming what I suspected .

Comment: actually I am not so sure, I do not see in the C++14  standard why `default_a` should not be accepted. it's a named lvalue with linkage and its address is a constant expression

Comment: maybe [temp.arg.nontype]/5.3: "For a non-type template-parameter of type reference to object, no conversions apply."  (so it is not allowed to perform conversion from derived to base reference)

Answer (score 1):

A gcc specific workaround:

```
struct a
{ int _v;
  constexpr a():_v(0){}
  constexpr a(int v): _v(v){} 
};

struct c: public a
{ constexpr c():a(){}
  constexpr c(int v):a(v){} 
};

extern const c _default_c;

constexpr const c _default_c { 1 };

extern const a default_a;

const a default_a __attribute__((alias("_default_c")));

template < const a & The_A = default_a >
struct b
{ constexpr static const a &the_a = The_A;
};

b<> a_b;
```

The above compiles OK .

Happily, we know that the name of '_default_c' is not mangled.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when initializing a `const` reference a temporary is created, and temporaries are not allowed with reference initialization in this context (converted constant expression).

N4140 8.5.3 (5.2.2.1)

> ...
>
> - If `T1` is a non-class type, a temporary of type "*cv1* `T1`" is created and copy-initialized (8.5) from the initializer expression.
>     The reference is then bound to the temporary.
>
> In all cases except the last (i.e., creating and initializing a
>   temporary from the initializer expression), the reference is said to
>   *bind directly* to the initializer expression.

Then in 5.19:

> A *conditional-expression* `e` is a *core constant expression* unless
>   the evaluation of `e`, following the rules of the abstract machine
>   (1.9), would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> (2.9)
>   -  an *id-expression* that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and
>   either
>
> - it is initialized with a constant expression or ...

Comment: Aha! Thanks for the standard document reference quotes - I will study further.
I look forward to C++-17 solving this cleanly - for now my gcc hack will do.

Comment: @JVD I can't find the language where it specifically says "binds directly" in N4140 but it's in the [latest draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#4). Will update answer later.

Comment: Unfortunately, all it takes to break is to place the above fragment in an enclosing namespace - then the '_default_c' name is mangled.

Comment: @JVD Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33301552/non-type-reference-parameter-argument)

Comment: A temporary is not created when binding a reference to `T` to an object of type `T` or derived from `T`. You quoted the case for non-class type, but `a` is a class type

Answer (score 0):

Fix that works in namespace:

```
namespace U {
    struct a
    { int _v;
      constexpr a():_v(0){}
      constexpr a(int v): _v(v){} 
    };

    struct c: public a
    { constexpr c():a(){}
      constexpr c(int v):a(v){} 
    };
    extern "C" {
    extern const c _default_c;

    constexpr const c _default_c { 1 };
    }

    extern const a default_a;

    const a default_a __attribute__((alias("_default_c")));

    template < const a & The_A = default_a >
    struct b
    { constexpr static const a &the_a = The_A;
    };

    b<> a_b;
}
```