# Why is address of non-static member not allowed as template non-type parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

```
template <int* ip> struct test {};

struct q {
    static int a;
    int b;
    
    constexpr q(int b_) : b(b_) {}
};

int i;
constexpr q q0(2);

int main()
{
    constexpr test<&i> t1;      // Works fine
    constexpr test<&q::a> t2;   // Works 
    constexpr test<&q0.b> t3;   // Does not work; address of non-static member?
    
    return 0;
}
```

The declaration of t3 in the above piece of code fails despite the template argument `&q0.b` being known during compile time. Some googling revealed that this is disallowed by the standard (section 14.3.2):

> [Note: Addresses of array elements and names or addresses of non-static class members are not acceptable template-arguments.
>
> X<&s.m> x4; // error: address of non-static membe

So why exactly is this explicitly disallowed by the standard despite the addresses of non-static members of global variables being unique as well as known during compile-time?

Comment: I tried this on gcc 5.1.1 and clang 3.5.0 with -std=c++11

Comment: No `(new q)->b` is not known at  compile time

Comment: It's type is not `int*`, it's `int q::*`, isn't it?

Comment: @DieterLücking: Why wouldn't the compiler know the address of q0 and q0.b if it know the address of i?

Comment: Barry left an answer(*now deleted*), but seems like it was quoting the latest draft and you are using C++11 and [the wording he was quoting has changed a lot between C++11 and C++1z](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27411367/1708801)

Comment: Also the code does not compile as is, so that should be fixed or [even better provide a live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox).

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I deleted it because the question is more "why does this restriction exist" rather than "why does this code not compile?" Either way, it's disallowed in both wordings.

Comment: Template arguments must be mangled, and mangling (arbitrarily complex) references to subobjects is a huge can of worms.

Comment: @skypjack: &q0.b should be a regular `int *`, not a pointer-to-member

Comment: @T.C. that sounds like an answer.

Comment: No, it's not a static member, it's a data member, it is not an `int*`.

Comment: @skypjack You're right in saying it is not `int *` because it is `int const *`.

Comment: You're right. I got it. :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, to use pointers/references to subobjects, you'd need to be able to mangle them. That's a pretty big undertaking.

Second, and probably more importantly, from [N4198](http://wg21.link/N4198):

> The restriction that the constant expression must name a complete
>   object is retained to avoid aliasing problems with pointers to
>   subobjects:
>
> ```
> struct A { int x, y; } a;
> template<int*> struct Z;
> using B = Z<&a.x + 1>;
> using C = Z<&a.y>;
> // Are B and C the same type?
> ```

To quote [Richard Smith](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/26jBWYIBrp0/o74AWYXMWpMJ),

> The answer "yes" is problematic because there are things you can do
>   with a pointer to [`a.y`] that would have undefined behavior if
>   performed on a pointer past the end of [`a.x`] The answer "no" is
>   problematic because they (in typical implementations) represent the
>   same address.

Comment: +, main factors in a nutshell.

Comment: @T.C. Wouldn't we run into the same situation had x and y been static members or simple global variables? (I'm not an expert in C++; I'm just trying to understand :) )

Comment: @T.C. Your quote from Richard Smith seems to provide more reasonable argument: "Keep in mind that template parameters must be something that can be reasonably determined at compile-time and can mangled. General pointers are not known at compile-time (the runtime linker can move things around) and there aren't necessarily clear rules on how they should be mangled on all platforms."

Answer (score 1):

Replace your main with this piece of code

```
int main(void)
{    
constexpr static int bb = 5;    
constexpr test<&bb> t;    
return 0;
}
```

and you will receive the error bb cannot be used as a template argument because it has no linkage ( not to be mistaken with linker related staff ) .

Class data members cannot be accessed unless they are referenced through the object, and cannot be taken into account during template instantiation, since data members do not have linkage, i.e. they are not defined symbols and therefore cannot be used as template arguments.

That being said , doing a readelf you can verify this:

```
48: 00000000004006ac     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   14 q0


68: 000000000060097c     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS __bss_start
69: 0000000000600978     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   23 q::a
```

but there is no `q0.b` defined . The alternative would be to name (mangle) none static class members which would strip dynamic capabilities of the language.