# SFINAE with incomplete type template overload doesn't work with Clang while it works with GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, sfinae

I cannot compile the following snippet with Clang, while GCC has no problem:

```cpp
template <typename T, int variant=0>
struct FooCallerWrapper;

template <typename T>
struct FooCallerWrapper<T, 0>
{
    typedef int FooCallerType;
};

template<class SERVICE_T, int variant = 0>
class FooCaller
{
    template<typename Dummy>
    struct Void { typedef void type; };

    template<typename R = void, typename Enabled = void>
    struct EnableIfHasNextVariant { };

    template<typename R>
    struct EnableIfHasNextVariant<
        R,
        typename Void<typename FooCallerWrapper<SERVICE_T, variant+1>::FooCallerType>::type>
    {
        typedef R type;
    };
};

FooCaller<int> foo;
```

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38465615/code-using-sfinae-working-with-gcc-but-not-with-clang), but I cannot understand how to fix it in my case.

I tested with Clang 3.1, 8.0 and 10.0, and with GCC 5.1 and 9.3.

Comment: There is no SFINAE here. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953248/why-doesnt-sfinae-enable-if-work-for-member-functions-of-a-class-template).

Comment: @user1810087 it defeats the purpose, because your solution will allow EnableIfHasNextVariant even if the user hasn't defined a "next variant" for `FooCallerWrapper`